# How does rails know what attribute is the foreign key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I ran

```
    rails generate scaffold post title:string body:text
    rails generate scaffold comment post_id:integer body:text
    rake db:migrate
    rake routes
```

Then, in post.rb model, I did

```
    class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
    end
```

Then, in comment.rb model, I did

```
    class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :post
    end
```

The associations are working as intended. Yet, I can't figure out how Rails knows that 'post_id'
is a foreign key in the comments table? I specified it nowhere. Please explain the magic behind this.

PS: I am super noob.

Comment: Convention over configuration, a `Post` model will by default have `post_id` as a foreign key

Comment: So if I had named the attribute 'foo' instead of 'post_id', the whole thing wouldn't have worked?

Comment: it wouldn't, but then you can specify the foreign key explicitly `belongs_to :post, foreign_key: foo`

Comment: I get it, thanks to both of you. Besides, I now have also seen one live example of what 'convention over configuration' really means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you have "expanded" some of the Rails' convention into your migration.

This:

```
rails generate scaffold comment post_id:integer body:text
```

...could have been this:

```
rails generate scaffold comment post:references body:text
```

...so you specify not some **magic attribute name** that somehow happens to be **an integer**, but a model name you are referencing, that you know for sure.

Of course, those two do the same things. It's a convention, but you can always override it, as specified in [the guides (4.1.2.5)](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#updating-the-schema):

> By convention, Rails assumes that the column used to hold the foreign
>   key on this model is the name of the association with the suffix `_id`
>   added. The `:foreign_key` option lets you set the name of the foreign
>   key directly

Comment: @Ahtsham yeah. The rate drops after a while, but value of the gained experience rises.