# Can I test whether an ActiveRecord's attribute is a foreign key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys

Other than asking whether its name ends in `_id`?

If I were to test attributes in the above way, would it be generalizable?  Doing so would absolutely suffice for my present use case.  But I might in some alternate universe want to make a gem of some of the tools I'm forging.  I'm guessing those who really want to can set up models with foreign keys that don't end in `_id`.  [D-Side](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25715385/948073) pointed me to [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#updating-the-schema):

> By convention, Rails assumes that the column used to hold the foreign
>   key on this model is the name of the association with the suffix `_id`
>   added. The `:foreign_key` option lets you set the name of the foreign
>   key directly

Is there a way to detect cases where someone has gone with the second option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to get a list of foreign keys with something like:

```
all_reflections = self.class.reflections.
                      select{ |n, r| r.macro == :belongs_to }.
                      map{ |name, reflection| reflection.foreign_key }
```

If you're going to do it often I would cache the result